# How can i get user role from LDAP with spring security

Tags: spring-security-ldap

I am able to connect with ldap and getting response, But in my Principal object  authorities size is zero in which the role details is available i guess.
What are the additional input i need to pass in order to get ldap role details?

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.ldapAuthentication()
        .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=TestOu")
        .contextSource()
        .url("ldaps://XX:768");
        }
```

i tried with DirContextOperations object also ,it contains many attributes except role, The role is defined in ldapit and i am able to get the role while running the ldap query,
the issue is only through spring security

Please help

Answer (score 0):

A 'role' does not really mean anything for an LDAP Directory Server.

LDAPv3 knows only about static groups.

Some LDAP Directory Server products allows to retrieve group memberships from a 'dynamic attribute' at the entry level.

You may define 'role' as an attribute for entries.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer Bernhard,

it is already defined in ldap ,  and i am able to get the role while running the ldap query,the issue is only through spring security

Comment: Authentication with LDAP means , perform an LDAP SEARCH operation to retrieve  the DN of an entry and then use that DN together with the provided password to perform an LDAP BIND operation.
Do you want to populate the LdapUserDetails object with specific attributes or do you want to use the value of the 'role' attribute to assign Spring Security roles?

Comment: Are you performing the ldap query with an LDAP connection beeing authenticated as the 'user DN' or as an 'administrative DN'?

Comment: I am able to login with LDAP configuration,And i need to
set User role (meaning,role attribute value from LDAP) in httpSession, But the role vale is not returning from LDAP .response object having lot of values like email,uid,employeNumber ..etc ,except user role.
 Through ldapsearch , and run command directly i am able to see the result

Comment: Then the LDAP Directory Server has access control restrictions to return the attribute. If you do not specify so called 'return attributes' , which would be best practise, then all attributes are returned the binding DN is allowed to see. You may just compare the access log entries for the Spring based query with the one performed using ldapsearch. I suspect in the further case the User DN is used.

Comment: I tried using ldap template and that worked only with a specific condition ,That we have to use SearchControls (javax.naming.directory.SearchControls) and specify the ReturningAttributes (void javax.naming.directory.SearchControls.setReturningAttributes(String[] attrs)) with few parameters. With this it returned all the role information for that user. I tried with the same user so it is not because of the access privilege

Answer (score 0):

Got it !!!!! implementing a custom AuthenticationProvider and LdapAuthenticator and it used BindAuthenticator. We have to set the following with BindAuthenticator

```
     authenticator.setUserDnPatterns(new String[]{"XX"});
     authenticator.setUserAttributes(new String[]{"nsrole"});
```

In Config

@Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

```
    auth.authenticationProvider(this.customLdapAuthenticationProvider());
}

@Bean(name = "ldapAuthenticationProvider")
public AuthenticationProvider customLdapAuthenticationProvider() {

    LdapUserDetailsMapper userDetailsMapper = new UserMapper();

    CustomLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new CustomLdapAuthenticationProvider(this.ldapAuthenticator(),
            new NullLdapAuthoritiesPopulator());
    provider.setUserDetailsContextMapper(userDetailsMapper);

    return provider;

}

@Bean(name = "ldapAuthenticator")
public LdapAuthenticator ldapAuthenticator() {

    BindAuthenticator authenticator = new BindAuthenticator(this.contextSource());
    authenticator.setUserDnPatterns(new String[] { "uid={0},ou=people" });
    authenticator.setUserAttributes(new String[] { "nsrole" });
    return authenticator;
}

@Bean(name = "contextSource")
public DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource() {

    DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource = new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource(ldapUrl);
    return contextSource;
}
```

private class UserMapper extends LdapUserDetailsMapper {

```
    @Override
    public UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx, String username,
            Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {


        List<GrantedAuthority> roles = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

        Attributes attrs = ctx.getAttributes();

            Sysout(attr)
        UserDetails userDetails = super.mapUserFromContext(ctx, username, roles);

        return userDetails;
    }
```

}